# What is the best way to wait until a runnable on the main thread completes in Android?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, concurrency

I need to collect a username and password from a user inside [`WebViewClient#shouldInterceptRequest`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldInterceptRequest%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29), so I must block the `WebView` IO thread until the user supplies a username and password on the main thread. What is the best way to wait until my runnable completes?

My current favorite way is (exceptions and timeouts omitted for brevity):

```
final CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    callSomethingWithAsyncCallback(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        countDownLatch.countDown();
      }
    });
  }
});
countDownLatch.await();
```

Something that uses [`ExecutorService`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html)s seems better since I can simply use [`Future#get`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get%28%29) to block. However, there is no `ExecutorService` that runs on the main thread, and using one from [`Executors`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) just to bounce it to the main thread seems wasteful. Thoughts?

Comment: Why dont you use Asyntask rather than runnable

Comment: I want the opposite of an `AsyncTask`: something that blocks a background thread until completion and runs on the main thread.

Comment: You can make use of preExecute and postExecute methods of AsynTask for your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Please use AsyncTask rather than using runnable.

- The AsyncTask executes everything in doInBackground() inside of another thread, which does not have access to the GUI where your views are.
- preExecute() and postExecute() offer you access to GUI before and after the heavy lifting occurs in this new thread, you can even pass the result of the long operation to postExecute() to then show any results of processing.

Comment: I want the object to block the calling thread until completion. `AsyncTask` is asynchronous. Also, I don't want to access the GUI before and after my task. I want the task to run on the GUI thread, and I my calling thread to unblock after the task is complete.

Comment: please go through this     http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html

Comment: What you've stated in your answer is factually correct, but does not answer my question.

Comment: Yes. I did not answer your question. But I showed another good and android recommended way of doing it.

Comment: That belongs in a comment instead of an answer then.